# If $\operatorname{rowspace}(A) = \operatorname{nullspace}(A)$, then does $A$ contains an even number of columns.

Tags: linear-algebra

If $\operatorname{rowspace}(A) = \operatorname{nullspace}(A)$,  then $A$ contains an even number of columns. 
is the statement true or false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Let $A:V\to V$ be a linear operator, and note that by rank-nullity we have
$$\begin{align*}
\dim V &= \mathrm{rank}(A)+\mathrm{nullity}(A)\\
&=\mathrm{dim}(\mathrm{rowspace}(A))+\mathrm{dim}(\mathrm{nullspace}(A))\\
&=\mathrm{dim}(\mathrm{rowspace}(A))+\mathrm{dim}(\mathrm{rowspace}(A))\\
&=2\cdot \mathrm{dim}(\mathrm{rowspace}(A))
\end{align*}$$
and so $V$ has even dimension, which is the number of columns of $A$.

Comment: why did you replace dim(nullspace(A)) with 2???

Comment: @JohnathonSvenkat Because $\dim(\mathrm{nullspace}(A))=\dim(\mathrm{rowspace}(A))$.